# Exceptions in MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 161

Tags: perl, mongodb

Using MongoDB 2.4.5 with version 0.702 of the Perl MongoDB driver, I frequently run into exceptions like these:

```
recv timed out (30000 ms) at ...MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 161.

couldn't get response to throw out at ...MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 161.

missed the response we wanted, please try again at ...MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 161

invalid header received at ...MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 161.

can't get db response, not connected at ...MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 161.
```

The exceptions are intermittent, and often vanish on the next request (this is a web app).  Occasionally, the exceptions will persist over several consecutive requests.

This is a tiny database running the default configuration (no sharding or anything fancy).  I've tried using some of the tools listed [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/), but I'm unclear on how to apply them to this situation.

This is all running on Debian 7.1 64-bit.  The web server is Mojolicious' hypnotoad 4.07 on perl 5.16.3 running behind apache2.

Can you kindly suggest some tools & strategies for diagnosing the problem?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Follow the instruction on the first link, what does /var/log/messages says ?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, on what platform is the web app running? (mod_perl, PSGI, etc?) What OS?

Comment: @lc2817 /var/log/messages says quite a lot, but nothing about mongo or mongod.  The server didn't stop, it just failed to answer some requests.  But I will keep looking through the logs to see if something pops out.

Comment: @friedo I've added the OS and Perl version info to the original post.  I expect this is entirely due to something going on in my environment, not a bug in the driver.  I'm mostly looking for tips on how to diagnose this sort of problem in general.

Comment: Have you tried testing the app with only one web server involved? i.e. only using hypnotoad or apache2?  It seems like your app may have an issues with stale cursors; you could also check your [connection timeout](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Connection.pm#timeout) settings.

Comment: I've seen this when the cursor size is over 100 items.  I'm looking for a fix and will post back if I find something.  Saw a python driver JIRA entry that was similar.